# How to calculate sum of first n elements in dataframe column by condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlcug.png)

how to calculate sum of lets 3 first negative elements of first column?

I tried loc and ilocs but they sum all negative elements in column. I expected -3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Filter first negative values - less like `0`, then first 3 and `sum`:

```
out = df.loc[df.a.lt(0), 'a'].head(3).sum()

out = df.loc[df.a.lt(0), 'a'].iloc[:3].sum()
```

EDIT: If need first column select by positionm not by label `a`:

```
out = df.iloc[df.iloc[:, 0].lt(0).to_numpy(), 0].iloc[:3].sum()
```

Comment: great answer Jezrael!